# something wrong in dealing with xmlhttp request text-response

Tags: javascript, ajax

HTML:

```
        <div id="phone" onclick="getNum('ph')" class="onClic">phone number</div>
        <div id="fax" onclick="getNum('fx')" class="onClic">fax number</div>
```

---

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getNum(rq){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.responseText.trim()!="fail"){
                        if(rq=="ph"){
                        document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML="99066744";
                        }else if(rq=="fx"){
                        document.getElementById("fax").innerHTML="93393368";
                        }
                        alert("done");
                    }else{
                        alert("something went wrong");
                    }
                    }

xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/getnum.php?idu=1&rq="+rq,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

`getnum.php` outputs either nothing or `"fail"`. when I trigger the JavaScript by clicking 
on either `phone` or `fax` elements, I get the `alert("something went wrong")` twice and then I get `alert("done")`. **everything is working fine except that I should not get `alert("something went wrong")` as long as the request is successful.** what could be wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is most likely because most (modern'ish') browsers will fire the readyState events `1`, `2` and especially `3`. `readyState 3` is the such called interactive mode which fires during a request so you can intercept and spot data while its still streaming.

So in short words, your `onreadystatechange` handler gets called several times (thats how it should be) and since you're checking for `readyState === 4` it will call your `else` case for all the other cases.

To determine if something really went wrong, you should just check for `status codes` individually there.